# Display image in Django Form

Tags: python, django

I need to display an image in a Django form. My Django form is quite simple - a single text input field. When I initialise my Django form in a view, I would like to pass the image path as a parameter, and the form when rendered in the template displays the image. Is is possible with Django forms or would i have to display the image separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is related to the form itself, not to any field in particular, then you can make a custom form class and override one of **as_table()**, **as_ul()**, **as_p()** methods. Or you can just use a custom template instead of leaving the form to render itself.
If it is field related then a custom widget is appropriate, as Pierre suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This template responsibility to display this image in your case, I believe.
If you form need to be able to send image related information (path, url..), you'll need to create a dedicated widget.